# How to get value of directive in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've made custom element directive. I would like to know how to get value from the scope of directive or from attribute.

```
<my-element my-attr="??" ng-click="myFunction(VALUE_OF_MY_ATTR)" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you bind `myAttr` via two way binding in your directive you can simply pass it with the same name to your function, because the scope of the myFunction is set by the ngClick directive.

```
// template
<div ng-controller="someController">
    myModel: {{ myModel }}
    <my-element my-attr="myModel" ng-click="myFunction(myModel)" />
</div>

// js
angular.module("myModule").controller("someController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.myModel = { number: 42 };
    $scope.myFunction = function (data) { console.log(data); }
}).directive("myElement", function ($interval) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: { // define an isolated scope for you directive
            myAttr: "=", // set two-way-binding for 'my-attr'
        },
        link: function ($scope, $element, attributes) {
            // count up the number in myModel.
            // myModel can be accessed via myAttr because it is defined
            // in the scope of the directive.
            $interval(function () {
                // you can access
                $scope.myAttr.number += 1;
            }, 1000);
        }
    };
});
```

You can see a working example in the Plunker link.

**Important**: You can not access `$scope.myModel` in the directive, because you isolated you scope and you have to use `$scope.myAttr` If you don't set a scope attribute you get the same scope as outside of the directive, but then you don't get the easy aliasing and have to evaluate you directive attributes on you own `$scope.$eval(attributes.myAttr)`.

[Example on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PoxliiVgX0FETTxMkgwm)

Comment: But how to make it work without any input? Value of attribute is changed by directive.